# While performing logistic regression i get the error : LinAlgError: Singular matrix

Tags: python, logistic-regression, data-analysis

I am using the Lending Club Data. I am using the following code.

I have a dataframe X containing all the predictor columns and Y containing the output whether the loan is good or bad

```
#Here we change the good loans to 1 and bad loans to 0
mask = (Y['loan_condition'] == 'Good Loan')
Y['loan_condition'] = np.where(mask, 1, 0)


#Train Test Split and performing SMOTE
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
os = SMOTE(random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, 
random_state=0)
columns = X_train.columns
os_data_X,os_data_Y=os.fit_sample(X_train, Y_train)
os_data_X = pd.DataFrame(data=os_data_X,columns=columns )
os_data_Y= pd.DataFrame(data=os_data_Y,columns=['loan_condition'])


X=np.array(os_data_X)
Y=np.array(os_data_Y)


#Performing Logistic Regression
import statsmodels.api as sm
logit_model=sm.Logit(Y,X)
result=logit_model.fit()
print(result.summary2())
```

**ERROR/WARNING:**

Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
         Current function value: inf
         Iterations: 35

LinAlgError: Singular matrix

Can someone help me here? Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a LinAlgError: Singular matrix, it means that your X matrix is linearly dependent ( <=> discriminant is equal to zero).  In other words, Xn = akXk + ...+amXm

Thus, you have to change your X matrix. If you look at your correlation metrics, it may bring you some ideas. Or you may mess up with dummy variables. For an example, if you have 3 categories: cat, dog and fish, you need only 2, not 3 marked with zeros and ones.